# Float not working when used with child inline-block element

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float, sidebar

I'm trying to create a layout where there is a sidebar like heading and intro, next to a grid of cards. However, when I try to use float, the display:inline-block styling of the the div's child element seems to be causing problems (it works when I use display:block on the child element). Any alternative solutions are appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/e_video/hdd0wr1p/

HTML

## Title Example

Descrition of different things on different subjects.

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <h1>
    Title Example
  </h1>
  <p>
  Descrition of different things on different subjects.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="card-section">
  <article class="card"></article>
  <article class="card"></article>
  <article class="card"></article>
  <article class="card"></article>
  <article class="card"></article>
  <article class="card"></article>
</div>
<br/>
```

CSS

```
.card{
  background: red;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

.card-section,
.sidebar{
  float:left; 
}
```

Comment: It's not that the inline-block elements don't work, it's because once you declare float on the container, the width of the container is no longer spanning the entire width

Answer (score 0):

Works fine, you just have to declare a width less than 100% --https://jsfiddle.net/hdd0wr1p/2/ or https://jsfiddle.net/hdd0wr1p/4/ or https://jsfiddle.net/hdd0wr1p/5/

What's happening...

`h1` is a block element designed to clear other elements. By default, `h1` is a block at 100% the width of its parent element. In this case, without a width on the sidebar, that is 100% the window width.

It's the `h1` tags that are clearing your floats. By setting a width to either the sidebar itself, or the `h1` tags, the floats work. Setting a width to the sidebar restricts the width of the child `h1` tags as well.